# Flutter App dies with "Failed assertion: line 4901 pos 16: 'child is! ParentDataElement<ParentData>': is not true."

Tags: python, android, selenium, flutter

I'll get right to it. My app crashes with the error specified in the title, and after significant digging around I have yet to find a solution.

### What should this do and what is the problem?

Opening the application brings up the main menu (mainView.dart) and if you have the server.py running and have remembered to put in the correct IP addresses and ports so that your phone can talk to your computer inside the same LAN, you should be set to reproduce the bug. In youtube view, you should be able to paste a link to a youtube video of your choosing and have the server script prompt Selenium webdriver to play said video on a browser window. However, while the video plays correctly and such, sending the link causes the entire app to break, symptoms being crashes in the media control widget as well as the main view, should you return to it.

Connector class is written as a singleton and should provide up to date data to the GUI widgets based on JSON strings sent by the sendSystemState function in server.py. Updates are handled by the Providers.

I have no idea what causes the error messages, and neither do I have any idea on how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Reproducing the bug

1. Run main.py with server.py in the same folder
2. start up the application
3. hit the youtube button
4. Paste a youtube video URL to the text field and hit the trailing icon button
5. let Selenium do its magic
6. by this point you should see the media control widget at the bottom of the youtube view break

### The code!

I couldn't paste all the code needed to reproduce the app and the issue here, so I made a gist-paste: [all the code used](https://gist.github.com/misovi/d7c17e7a4f3f23de026a96f2ce09d350)

On request I can post individula files, but I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to limit the required code while still being able to reproduce what's happening accurately.

Comment: this is your assert, no?  Include that bit in your post.  Also let us know why that assertion exists.

Comment: That is not an assert I made, it seems to be an assert baked into Flutter framework. If I made that assert myself, I'd have more idea where to startt looking :<

Comment: gotcha, not familiar with Flutter, but it doesn't seem to like your "Expanded" objects... it's pointing to lines 28, and 70 of MediaControllerWidget.dart file.

Comment: yep, but I have no idea why those components break when they do. They don't break when I tweak volume levels through the app and that uses the same mechanism as sending the youtube video link across, which does break the component. So I'm utterly lost.

Comment: @Narmondur I have the same issue now, I'm looking into it. If I found a solution I'll post here.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with flex layouts I think. I had an issue with a spacer which was ending up being placed inside a container. I think that was possibly causing the problem for me.

Comment: I had an issue with a spacer which was ending up being placed inside an Expanded. When I removed the Expanded and just used the Spacer (as both are a flex layout) it worked. I suspect the expanded's child was not expected to also be flex.

Answer (score 15):

Checking the logs you've provided, the error seems to point on `MediaControlWidget.dart`.

```dart
════════ (5) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4901 pos 16: 'child is! ParentDataElement<ParentData>': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Expanded file:///C:/Users/narmo/Documents/theBigApp/TheBigApp/remote_appv1/lib/MediaControlWidget.dart:28:9
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (6) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4901 pos 16: 'child is! ParentDataElement<ParentData>': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Expanded file:///C:/Users/narmo/Documents/theBigApp/TheBigApp/remote_appv1/lib/MediaControlWidget.dart:70:9
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I've tried running error-causing the snippet, and the ones causing the issue is how `Spacer` is used.

From your code, `Spacer` is used inside an `Expanded` widget, similar to this code.

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(flex: 1, child: Spacer()),
    Expanded(flex: 1, child: Container(color: Colors.greenAccent)),
    Expanded(flex: 1, child: Spacer()),
  ],
),
```

Since `Spacer` is an "Expanded widget", it should be used alongside `Expanded` widgets. It should be used similarly to this code.

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Spacer(flex: 1),
    Expanded(flex: 1, child: Container(color: Colors.greenAccent)),
    Spacer(flex: 1),
  ],
),
```

Comment: This was exactly the cause in my case. Thank you.